# How to get rid of unused $_GET parameters in URL with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am designing search functionality with some data with Codeigniter.

My search model looks like:

```
class Search_Model extends CI_Model {

        public function get_results($search_terms = false) {

            // Build query
            foreach ($search_terms as $field => $value) {
                $this->db->like("{$field}", $value);
            }

            // Execute query
            $query = $this->db->get('exams');

            // Return results
            return $query->result_array();
        }
}
```

And the search controller method looks like this:

```
public function results() {

            $search_terms = array(
                'first_name' => $this->input->get('first_name', TRUE),
                'last_name' => $this->input->get('last_name', TRUE),
                'exam_name' => $this->input->get("exam_name", TRUE)
            );

            $data['title'] = "Search Results";
            $data['exams'] = $this->search_model->get_results($search_terms);

            $this->load->view('templates/header.php', $data);
            $this->load->view('exams/index.php', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer.php');
}
```

The search is working as it should but I want to clean up the URL which comes out something like this if I only search for "First Name":

```
search/results?first_name=tim&last_name=&exam_name=
```

How can I remove those extra parameters that are unused in the URL?

Comment: where you set get URL ???

Comment: I have an index method in the search controller that sets the form method to GET since I want to see the search terms in the URL

Comment: you can do it simply with jquery. add your form code first in your question..

Comment: @TimothyFisher : why downvoted my ans ? your question was u wanted to remove the extra params from url. and my ans refers to that. i dont see your accepted ans removing the unnecessary fields from url ? then why downvoted mine ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslamTushar I was not the one that downvoted sorry. I am going to try your solution later in the development phases as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include jquery in your header. then add this script.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('action')+'?';
        var first = false;
        var second = false;
        if($('input[name="first_name"]').val()){
            url += 'first_name='+$('input[name="first_name"]').val();
            first = true;
        }
        if($('input[name="last_name"]').val()){
            if(first){
                url += '&';
            }
            url += 'last_name='+$('input[name="last_name"]').val();
            second = true;
        }
        if($('input[name="exam_name"]').val()){
            if(second){
                url += '&';
            }
            url += 'exam_name='+$('input[name="exam_name"]').val();
        }
        window.location.replace(url);
    });
});
</script>
```

(i didnt ran this script yet, so let me know if u get any syntax error or somethign else.)
and finally change your results function to this,

```
public function results() {

            $search_terms = array();

            if(isset($_GET['first_name'])){
                $search_terms['first_name'] = $this->input->get('first_name', TRUE);
            }
            if(isset($_GET['last_name'])){
                $search_terms['last_name'] = $this->input->get('last_name', TRUE);
            }
            if(isset($_GET['exam_name'])){
                $search_terms['exam_name'] = $this->input->get('exam_name', TRUE);
            }

            $data['title'] = "Search Results";
            $data['exams'] = $this->search_model->get_results($search_terms);

            $this->load->view('templates/header.php', $data);
            $this->load->view('exams/index.php', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer.php');
}
```

Comment: I just got home and was able to try this. After trying this solution this is what actually worked. Yada's answer did filter through the PHP array but the parameters were still showing up in the URL. Using JS re-formatted the url nicely!!

Comment: @TimothyFisher : thank you very much for trying this. and i am glad to know that this solved your problem. and sorry for misunderstanding. just wondering who downvoted without any reason. anyway thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way is just to filter the $searh_terms array before passing it to the model.

```
$search_terms = array(
    'first_name' => $this->input->get('first_name', TRUE),
    'last_name' => $this->input->get('last_name', TRUE),
    'exam_name' => $this->input->get("exam_name", TRUE)
);

// Remove empty search values
foreach ($search_terms as $key => $value) {
    if (strlen($value) == 0) {
         unset($search_terms[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what about `submit=submit_button_value`? Is there are any way to hide it from URL (first time when form submitted)?

Comment: Wouldn't `array_filter` do the same thing?

Comment: This worked best for me. I will look into `array_filter` as well, thanks everyone for the suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

**You can try this:**

```
$mode = array();
    if(isset($_GET['first_name'])):
        $mode[] = 'first_name='.$_GET['first_name']; 
    endif; 

    if(isset($_GET['last_name'])):
        $mode[] = 'last_name='.$_GET['last_name'];
    endif; 

    if(isset($_GET['exam_name'])):    
        $mode[] = 'exam_name='.$_GET['exam_name'];
    endif;

    //etc...

    //Then reformulate link 
    if(!empty($mode)){
        $link = '?' . implode('&',$mode);
    }else{
        $link = '';
    }

  redirect("form.php".$link);
```

Answer (score -1):

just filter what you send...

```
foreach ($search_terms as $field => $value) {
            if ($value <> ""){ //or the test you like to use...
                $this->db->like("{$field}", $value);
            }
        }
```